# JPA Two ElementCollections of same type in same class

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA2 specification with hibernate as my persistence provider. Can someone guide me on how to map two element collections of same type in the same class? For e.g.

```
 public class Employee {
     @Id //...
     private Long id;

     @ElementCollection         
     private Collection<String> tempAddresses;

     @ElementCollection         
     private Collection<String> permanentAddresses;

 }
```

With the default mappings during load hibernate is not able to distinguish between the two list since they are mapped with the same join column (i.e. id column).

**Edit 1**
I forgot to mentioned that my requirement is to map both the element collection to the same table since both are addresses. So the mappings should look like

`public class Employee {
         @Id //...
         private Long id;`

```
     @ElementCollection     
     @CollectionTable(name = "ADDRESS", joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID"))    
     @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
     private Collection<String> tempAddresses;

     @ElementCollection         
     @CollectionTable(name = "ADDRESS", joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID"))    
     @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
     private Collection<String> permanentAddresses;

 }
```

Because both the collections are mapped to the same collection table and they get joined with the same id column, hence during load hibernate cannot differentiate which addresses are temporary and which are permanent.

Comment: Adding two element collections of the same type in a same class and in the same database table. Thats the problem

Answer (score 2):

> With the default mappings during load hibernate is not able to distinguish between the two list since they are mapped with the same join column (i.e. id column).

Well, no!  With the default mappings, hibernate will distinguish between the two lists by storing them in different tables.

> my requirement is to map both the element collection to the same table since both are addresses.

They are both addresses.  But they have different uses, which you clearly wish to distinguish.  If you're using the `@ElementCollection` annotation to map them, the sensible way to distinguish them is to put them in different tables.

Another (more traditional) approach would be to make an address entity instead of representing them as plain strings, and use `@OneToMany` annotations to connect them to your Employee class.  Then all the addresses could indeed be in the same table, but hibernate would build join tables connecting them to the Employee table.  There would still be two join tables.